# How can i call AnotherSubFunction using my obj

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {

    MainFunction: function() {
       AnotherSubFunction: function() {

       } 
       var variable = AnotherSubFunction ()

    }

}
```

- Can i do something like this...
- How can i call AnotherSubFunction using my obj? Is it possible.
- How to create a function inside another function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question is not valid Javascript. You're probably looking for:

```
MainFunction: function() {
    function AnotherSubFunction() {
        // ...
    } 

    var variable = AnotherSubFunction();
}
```

Or maybe:

```
MainFunction: function() {
    AnotherSubFunction = function() {
        // ...
    } 

    var variable = AnotherSubFunction();
}
```

However, in both cases, the name `AnotherSubFunction` associated with the nested function only exists in the scope of the enclosing function (`MainFunction`) and will not be accessible directly from `obj`.